# Xcode 8 - Why do Project & Target settings have the option of different deployment target versions?

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode 8.3.2
Here are the screenshots from the same test project.

1. Select "Project" you can choose the deployment target IOS version

[image: Project screenshot]
2. Select "Target" you get another choice of deployment target version

[image: Target Screenshot]
I am probably missing something, but I don't understand the benefit of the 2 separate choices!
(I have shown them as different here, but in my real project I always set them the same).

Answer (score 2):

A project can have multiple targets. It's possible that some of the targets could have a older or newer Deployment Target than the rest of the targets.

The project-level lets you set the most common Deployment Target used by most targets. You can then adjust a specific target to have a different Deployment Target if needed.

When you only have one target, it doesn't matter which you change, the project or the target.